# Ordering users by reputation in search

Tags: feature-request, users, users-page

When searching generic names ("John" for example) it may be useful to order the results by reputation since only the first X are shown, and I'm more likely to find the John I'm looking for if the ones with 1 reputation are filtered out instead of what appears to be random ordering.

Comment: Greatly (5x-10x) increasing the number of results may also help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm agree, Not only sorting but also when the search results does not fit in one page, It would be great to have pagination option too. I think its currently showing first page only.

When I browse [filter/john](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/filter/john) page directly, looks like there is another page too

[alt text http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1193/userpage.gif](http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/1193/userpage.gif)